# How do I transfer solana tokens to multiple wallets

Tags: airdrop

I want to do a token airdrop
Is there an already prewritten script to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example showing creation of a mint, associated token accounts and finally an airdrop. It is likely using an older version of solana/web3.js, so new syntax/functions might be a bit different.

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { YourProgram } from "../target/types/yourprogram";
import { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey, Signer } from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  createMint,
  createAccount,
  getAccount,
  getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
  transfer,
  mintTo,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

describe("Test of your program", async () => {  
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.local();
  const program = anchor.workspace.YourProgram as Program<YourProgram>;

  // constants
  const LAMPORTS_PER_SOL = 1000000000;  

  // Accounts   
  const testwallet1 = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const testwallet2 = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const transactionPayer = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const mintAuthSC = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const mintKeypairSC = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  let mintSC: PublicKey;  

  // Associated Token Accounts
  let testwallet1ATA;  

  before(async () => {
    // Top-ups
    {
      await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(
        await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
          transactionPayer.publicKey,
          2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
        )
      );
      await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(
        await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
          mintAuthSC.publicKey,
          2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
        )
      );
      await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(
        await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
          testwallet1.publicKey,
          2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
        )
      );
    }
    
    mintSC = await createMint(
      provider.connection,
      transactionPayer,
      mintAuthSC.publicKey,
      mintAuthSC.publicKey,
      10,
      mintKeypairSC,
      undefined,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    testwallet1ATA = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      provider.connection,
      transactionPayer,
      mintSC,
      testwallet1.publicKey
    );

    await mintTo(
      provider.connection,
      transactionPayer,
      mintSC,
      testwallet1ATA.address,
      mintAuthSC,
      1000,
      [],
      undefined,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );
  });

  it("Test 1", async () => {})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few public airdrop tools floating around on Github. Here's tje repo for one from the SAMO project: https://github.com/praskoson/distribution-tools

Answer (score 0):

```
const {Connection,clusterApiUrl,Keypair,LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,} = require("@solana/web3.js");

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "processed");
const wallet = Keypair.generate();
const airdropTxSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
    wallet.publicKey,
    1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
  );
```